# firebase messages unexpectedly found nil

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I have a tableviewcontroller that has a list of all the messages a logged in user has sent any user of hi/her choice in the app:

The messages between the logged in user and any other user of the app is appended and displayed in the tableviewcell using this code:

```
func loadData()
{

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

        if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            for post in postsDictionary {
                let messages = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                for (id, value) in messages {
                    let info = value as! [String: AnyObject]


                    let convoId = info["convoId"]
                    let toId = info["ReceiverId"] as! String!
                    let fromId = info["senderId"] as! String!


                    if (toId == self.loggedInUserUid  || fromId == self.loggedInUserUid) {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages").child(convoId as! String)
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in



        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let message = Message(dictionary: dictionary)
            //                self.messages.append(message)

            if let receiver = message.convoId {
                self.messagesDictionary[receiver] = message

                self.messages = Array(self.messagesDictionary.values)
                print(self.messages)
                self.messages.sort(by: { (message1, message2) -> Bool in


                    return (message1.timestamp?.int32Value)! > (message2.timestamp?.int32Value)!

                })
            }

            //this will crash because of background thread, so lets call this on dispatch_async main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.MessageTableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)}
                }

            }}})

}
```

However, when I click a cell, I would like to go to a detailed view controller that shows the messages between the logged in user and the user of the cell clicked, so i use this code to segue:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

             let message = messages[indexPath.row]

            if message.ReceiverId != self.loggedInUserUid {
                var newVariable = message.ReceiverId


                if let userpicuid =  newVariable {

                    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(userpicuid)

                    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot)
                        in

                        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                            for post in dictionary {
                                let messages = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                                for (id, value) in messages {

                                    let username = messages["username"] as? String
                                    self.userpicuid = userpicuid
                                    self.username = username


                                }}}})}} else if message.senderId != self.loggedInUserUid {
                let newVariable = message.senderId

                if let userpicuid =  newVariable {

                    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(userpicuid)

                    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot)
                        in

                        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                            for post in dictionary {
                                let messages = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                                for (id, value) in messages {

                                    let username = messages["username"] as? String
                                    self.userpicuid = userpicuid
                                    self.username = username
                                }}}})}

            }

       performSegue(withIdentifier: "MessageNow", sender: self)

    }


    override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard segue.identifier == "MessageNow", let chatVc = segue.destination as? SendMessageViewController else {
            return
        }

        print(self.userpicuid)

        chatVc.senderId = self.loggedInUser?.uid
        chatVc.receiverData = self.userpicuid 
        chatVc.senderDisplayName = self.userpicuid
        chatVc.username = self.username

    }
```

However, when I click on the cell, I get the error **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** So I included some print statements to find out where the nil is. Turns out userpicuid and username is returning nil. I am not sure what I am doing wrong especially because my code is checking the receiverId and the senderId and is one of them is not the logged in user's uid then that uid should be the senderId that segues to the detailed messages.

The error is on the let receiverId = receiverData! line in the detailed messages view controller:

```
var receiverData: String?

     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
    let receiverId = receiverData!
            let receiverIdFive = String(receiverId.characters.prefix(5))
            let senderIdFive = String(senderId.characters.prefix(5))
            if (senderIdFive > receiverIdFive)
            {
                self.convoId = senderIdFive + receiverIdFive
            }
            else
            {
                self.convoId = receiverIdFive + senderIdFive
            }
    }
```

Comment: in which line your code broken ?

Comment: @KKRocks i updated the question

Comment: try to declare property as **var receiverData : String?**

Comment: @KKRocks still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the question using this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell", for: indexPath) as! MessageTableViewCell


    if message.ReceiverId != self.loggedInUserUid {
        var newVariable = message.ReceiverId

    if let imageName =  newVariable {

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(imageName)

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot)
            in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                for post in dictionary {
                    let messages = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                    for (id, value) in messages {


                        self.username = messages["username"] as? String
                        self.userpicuid = messages["uid"] as? String


            }}}})}}else if message.senderId != self.loggedInUserUid {
        let newVariable = message.senderId

        if let imageName =  newVariable {

            let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(imageName)

            ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot)
                in

                if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                    for post in dictionary {
                        let messages = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                        for (id, value) in messages {

                            self.username = messages["username"] as? String
                            self.userpicuid = messages["uid"] as? String

                        }}}})}
    }
    return cell
}


  override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard segue.identifier == "MessageNow", let chatVc = segue.destination as? SendMessageViewController else {
            return
        }


                                chatVc.senderId = self.loggedInUser?.uid
                                chatVc.receiverData = self.userpicuid
                                chatVc.senderDisplayName = self.userpicuid
                                chatVc.username = self.username




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this line:

`performSegue(withIdentifier: "MessageNow", sender: self)`

right here:

```
 let username = messages["username"] as? String
 self.userpicuid = userpicuid
 self.username = username
 performSegue(withIdentifier: "MessageNow", sender: self)
```

Comment: it outputted over a hundred nils and highlight that line as the source of the problem